# How can I make a notifyicon in C# alternate between two icons?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, notifyicon

Im using VS2010 with C# and a WinForm. When a certain condition is met, I would like the notifyicon in C# alternate between two icons. I see that the code below is created for a single icon but I can't see how to programmatically change it. The "((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon.Icon")))" part doesn't make sense to me.

```
notifyIcon.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon.Icon")));
```

I tried...

```
notifyIcon.Icon = (System.Drawing.Icon(Application.StartupPath + @"\noneed.ico"));
```

but wont work. I get the error "System.Drawing.Icon' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context"

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you forget to add a `new` keyword:

```
notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon( Application.StartupPath + @"\noneed.ico" );
```

Comment: It's amazing what a little word like "new" can do. hehe. Thanks

Comment: Also I would use System.IO.Path.Combine method to combine a path:

`notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "noneed.ico"));`